# How to add custom li item to wordpress menu

Tags: functions, menus, filters

I have tried to add custom `li` to my wordpress header menu using `functions.php`. Here is my code in `function` file.

```
function register_header_menu() {
   register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_header_menu' );
```

add new element to header menu

```
function add_new_item($items, $args) {
   if( $args->theme_location == 'header-menu' ){
    $items .= '<li> <a>Show whatever</a></li>';
}
    return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_new_item');
```

I'm using below code to add menu into `header.php`

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
  'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
  'container'    => 'ul',
  'menu_class' => 'menu',
) ); ?>
```

Menu is visible on header, but my new item is not visible in the menu. How can I fix it?

Comment: Your callback function is missing the `$args` arg because you didn't set the proper number of args passed to the function via `add_filter()`. `add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_new_item', 10, 2);` would fix it.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks for your answer, I have tried it but it's not working.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump( $args );` ? But you could also use the [`items_wrap`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#comment-204) option when you call `wp_nav_menu()`.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thank you very much, it's working now. Seems something wrong with my menu. I have deleted it and create a new one. Now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Default usage of `add_filter` looks like this:

```
add_filter( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )
```

As you can see, the default priority is 10 and by default only one param is passed.

In your code you need your filter to get 2 params, because [`wp_nav_menu_items`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_items/) takes 2 params (`$items` and `$args`) and you need both of them in your filter. So you have to pass 2 as number of params, when you add your filter:

```
function add_new_item_to_menu( $items, $args ) {
    if ( 'header-menu' == $args->theme_location ) {
        $items .= '<li><a>Show whatever</a></li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_new_item_to_menu', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Sometimes I wish that the number of callback input arguments would just be automatically counted as a default :-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Krzysiek Dróżdż's answer:

If you show menu in Elementor widget, you can't check `$args->theme_location`
So, I check by `$args->menu == 'primary-menu'`

Also it will be helpful if you show a menu in more then one place, this way, you can show it everywhere where menu with `primary-menu` is displayed.